# R studio: Changing all 585 row names

Tags: r

I have a dataset with in total 585 respondents. Now I want to change the row numbers in the right order (as you can see it goes from 1 to 2 to 4. I want to set it right for all 585 respondents. Now my last row number is 586 (Because it skipped 3).

I tried to do it manually with row.names(data_scenario_81)[row.names(data_scenario_81) == "3"] <- "2", it worked, however there are 585 respondents to do this for and that's a lot of work.

I also tried row.names(data_scenario_81)[row.names(data_scenario_81) == "4:586"] <- "3:585" but it does not work. Can someone help me with this code?

[image: 1]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to reset the row numbers you can use this statement:

```
rownames(data_scenario_81) <- NULL
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Have a great day!

Comment: @Mmij: please upvote or accept my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @DPH I think the OP doesn't have enough reputation to upvote.